# Return double* from c++ dll to delphi program

Tags: c++, delphi, pointers, dll, dllexport

Im trying to return the array of `double` (declared as double*) to delphi program. In c++ dll project I have

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )
extern double* array;
extern "C"
{
    DllExport double* SomeMethod(double);
}
```

and `array` got deleted when Dll is unloaded

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{

switch( ul_reason_for_call ) 
{ 
...

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        delete [] array;
        break;
}
    return TRUE;  // Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.
}
```

While I was testing my dll in c++ console application I got the right result after using `SomeMethod` from dll. Next i tried to test my dll in Delphi but the content of array returned by method is wrong. I used the following code.

```
TSomeMethod = function(level : Double): PDouble; cdecl;
...
var
    SomeMethod: TSomeMethod;
    arr: PDouble;
...
    if Assigned(SomeMethod) then
        begin
          arr:= SomeMethod(15);
          writeln(arr^:2:0);
          inc(arr);
          writeln(arr^:2:0);
        end
...
```

What is a proper way to return a `double*` from c++ dll to use in delphi?

P.S. Other methods work in th right way. For example dll returns `char*` and in delphi I got it using `PAnsiChar`

**UPDATE**

Here is some C++ code from file where `SomeMethod` is written.

```
double* array; // yea it's an array that declared as external in other file;
...
double* SomeMethod(double level)
{
    ...
    deque<double> arrayToReturn;
    ... // some actions with deque
    array= new double[arrayToReturn.size()];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<arrayToReturn.size(); i++)
        array[i] = arrayToReturn[i];
    return array;
 }
```

Comment: Do you have the code for SomeMethod()? When SomeMethod() returns all local variables in the method vanish so if you'r storing the value in a local variable in SomeMethod() it will be gone upon return. That might explain why the method returns garbage.

Comment: One other thing to check, what calling convention are you using for SomeMethod(), is it cdecl? It should be since your Delphi calls are declared as such.

Comment: Why is array extern? Where is the defining declaration? Show complete code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i used extern array because i need to use it in `SomeMethod` which is in another file. And I need my array to be in memory until Dll gets unloaded. In `SomeMethod` I  allocate memory for my array using `new` operator. And again in C++ console application my Dll returns correct array, but in Delphi it doesn't.

Comment: Can you show the code that loads the DLL and calls GetProcAddress. Can you show the output of the program? Can you show code on the C++ side that populates the array. Replace all the commented out stuff with code like array[0] = 42; and array[1] = 666;  It should be very easy to make an SSCCE.

Comment: I was confused about extern before. Now I understand. I'm sure you know, but the code will leak if SomeFunction is called more than once. But I guess this is example code for the question.

Comment: i think the general approach would be going "back to the roots" and opening in Delphi CPU view, then you would view in assembler level what would C++ use to pass the pointer, and what would Delphi use to obtain the pointer, and whether those assumptions would match.  Combining with "Divide and Conquer" approach that would be always waorking framework for any fixing problems like this. Just modify your code a little to make it easier. http://pastebin.com/JUVLCg4J  http://pastebin.com/H0D8mHQ8  - this trivial change would separate calclulations from transmitting - make it easy to spot and read

Comment: "Next i tried to test my dll in Delphi but the content of array returned by method is wrong" WHAT exactly is right or wrong ????????? Why you hide the information from those who could help you ?  @DavidHeffernan wanna bet that he has 1st (0th) number right and the rest are garbage? And am i right that his DLL leaks memory on every call but the last ?

Comment: @Arioch Delphi uses a non standard mechanism for return values. But when they fit in a register, Delphi matches C++. So, the Delphi declaration of the function matches C++. If we had SSCCE we could solve easily.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yea that's just an example. Strange thing: I tried to fill array with values as you say like array[0] = 42 etc. and it works fine in Delphi and in C++! If you saw in my update i use `for` loop to copy contents of a deque to the array. In C++ console application Dll returns right value but in Delphi doesn't in this scenario. Can it be the problem? But I dont understand how `deque` type can affect delphi program if I copy values to another place in memory and dont use `deque` as a return type.

Comment: @Mitya "In SomeMethod I allocate memory for my array using new operator" - but you do not FREE it. What if your SomeMethod would be called twice before DLL unloaded ? thrice ? 100000 times ?  Also, what if it NEVER been called, would array pointer be auto-initialized with NULL or will `free` just blow ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `Delphi uses a non standard mechanism` You meant pascal fastcall/register convention - but it is specially suppressed here by CDECL keyword (unless it should be `stdcall` or whatever - i know `extern "C"` suppress name mangling, but i ain't sure if it has any influence on calling convention used by C++ compiler). I expect (among two other things mentioned) C++ DLL to use just any random convention, so why i insist to look at the real implementation in CPU window

Comment: @Arioch'The I certainly did not mean that. For all calling conventions, Delphi treats return values larger than pointer size in  a non standard way. The C++ code uses cdecl.

Comment: Okay, seems i was wrong about `Inc(PDouble)` issue. To quote docwiki: "Also, if you declare a typed pointer with this directive ON, any variable of that type allows scaled pointer arithmetic and array indexing, *even after the directive has been turned OFF*" and i think PDouble was declared with PointerMath enabled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan did not knew that. but do `cdecl` and `stdcall` determine how data values larger than size_t should be passed ? Maybe they  - except for x87 registers - only allow returning of no more than single machine word ? If they do and Delphi ignores those rules, then that is a trap i never knew about. Anyway, in this particular case exactly the pointer is what the function returns, and this Delphi deficiency should not cause any influence.

Comment: @Arioch'The inc and dec do, and always have done, work with or without that directive. Return value abi differences exist for all conventions for larger than register pointers. Delphi treats return values as var parameter. So value is passed in as well as out. But other compilers on Windows treat return value with out semantics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, this seems to be a minor difference, assembler-wise. Almost neglectible. And anyway, not applicable to this code, dealing with PDouble.

Comment: @Arioch'The try returning wide string from a function. Match it with function returning BSTR on c++ side. See my list of questions. Or returning a large struct. It's a real issue, albeit not widely known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question works fine. Which means that the problem lies elsewhere. Here's the proof:

**C++**

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) double* SomeMethod(double)
{
    double* array = new double[2];
    array[0] = 42;
    array[1] = 666;
    return array;
}

}
```

**Delphi**

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

type
  TSomeMethod = function(level : Double): PDouble; cdecl;

var
  SomeMethod: TSomeMethod;
  arr: PDouble;
  lib: HMODULE;

begin
  lib := LoadLibrary('MyDll.dll');
  Win32Check(lib<>0);
  SomeMethod := GetProcAddress(lib, 'SomeMethod');
  Win32Check(Assigned(SomeMethod));
  arr:= SomeMethod(15);
  Writeln(arr^:3:0);
  inc(arr);
  Writeln(arr^:3:0);
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
 42
666
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. Indeed the problem was in the other part of DLL. I used the `floor` function in c++ code in some routine to compare two `double` values. For some reason in c++ and in delphi it gives the different results. Without `floor` everything works as i want.